# Spring and AJAX Form - how to send an Object Field

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I'm trying to send a DTO object via AJAX to my controller, but i don't know how to send an Object which is a field of my DTO because i can only send the id of the object...

My DTO is

```
public class ReservationDTO {


    private Plate plate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @NotNull
    private Date fromDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @NotNull
    private Date toDate;

    private Park park;

    //getters and setters
```

Then I have a form, with a select to choose the Plate

```
     <form th:action="@{/book/new}" method="POST"
        th:object="${reservation}"
        id="form-signin">
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="plate" th:text="#{reservation.plate }">Targa</label>
<div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
<select th:type="*{plate}" class="form-control" th:field="*{plate.plateId}">
<option th:each="p : ${plates}" th:value="${p.plateId}" th:text="${p.plateNumber}">Opzione</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group"> <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fromDate" th:text="#{reservation.from }"> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 input-group" id="datetimepicker2">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
                    </div>

        <input type="text" th:field="*{fromDate}" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
     <div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="toDate" th:text="#{reservation.to }"> </label>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4" id="datetimepicker3">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
     </div>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{toDate}" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-sm-4">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" th:text="#{reservation.getPrice}" id="priceButton">Conferma</button>
       </div>
            </form>
```

The script to send form data to the controller:

```
$(function() {
        $('#form-signin').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 

            var reservationJson = $('#form-signin').serialize();
            console.log(reservationJson);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/book/getPrice",
                data: reservationJson,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                     console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I would like to have this in my controller

```
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getReservationPrice(@RequestBody ReservationDTO dto){
// operations....
```

Submitting the form i get

```
plate.plateId=40&fromDate=26%2F04%2F2017+12%3A48&toDate=27%2F04%2F2017+12%3A49
```

which obviously isn't a ReservationDTO object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in the following way

HTML FORM:

```
<form th:action="@{/book/new}" method="POST"
   th:object="${reservation}"
   id="form-signin">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="plate" th:text="#{reservation.plate }">Targa</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
         <select th:type="*{plate}" class="form-control" th:field="*{plate.plateId}" id="selectedPlate">
            <option th:each="p : ${plates}" th:value="${p.plateId}" th:text="${p.plateNumber}">Opzione</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fromDate" th:text="#{reservation.from }"> </label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 input-group" id="datetimepicker2">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
         </div>
         <input type="text" th:field="*{fromDate}" id="fromDate" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="toDate" th:text="#{reservation.to }"> </label>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-4" id="datetimepicker3">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
         </div>
         <input type="text" th:field="*{toDate}" id="toDate" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row col-sm-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" th:text="#{reservation.getPrice}" id="priceButton">Conferma</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Then JS:

```
$(function() {
        $('#form-signin').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        var dati = new Object();
        dati.fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
        dati.toDate = $("#toDate").val();
            var selectedPlate = new Object();
            selectedPlate.id = $("#selectedPlate").val();
            selectedPlate.name = $("#selectedPlate").text();
            dati.plate = selectedPlate;
        dati.park = null;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/book/getPrice",
                data: JSON.stringify(dati),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                     console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

It should be OK and create a correct JSON structure

Angelo

**UPDATE**

```
$(function() {
            $('#form-signin').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            var dati = new Object();
            dati.fromDate = $("#fromDate").val();
            dati.toDate = $("#toDate").val();
                var selectedPlate = new Object();
                selectedPlate.id = $("#selectedPlate").val();
                selectedPlate.name = $("#selectedPlate option:selected").text();
                dati.plate = selectedPlate;
            dati.park = null;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/book/getPrice",
                    data: JSON.stringify(dati),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                         console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Angelo, but there is something which is still wrong... because i'm getting all the plates in this way... `{"fromDate":"26/04/2017 13:44","toDate":"27/04/2017 13:45","plate":{"id":"41","name":"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t123456768899\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t123457\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1234578910\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAAAAA\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t123\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t111111111\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"}`

Comment: @besmart soorry i was wrong. You should use `$("#selectedPlate option:selected").text();` in order to get the text of the selected plate. Let me know if it's OK. In the meantime I'll update the answer

Comment: You should put option:selected also on selectedPlate.id = $("#selectedPlate").val(); to be complete. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found a much more simpler way to achieve this. Instead of passing the object as a JSON, you can simply use `form.serializeArray()` as your data and expect a `@ModelAttribute` in your controller. Something like this should do the trick.

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/book/getPrice",
    data: $('#form-signin').serializeArray(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function() { ... }
});
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/book/getPrice")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getReservationPrice(@ModelAttribute ReservationDTO dto) { 
    // Operations. 
}
```

**Note:** Remeber to add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller's method.